# Flutter: how to set PersistentFooterButtons background?

Tags: flutter, layout

Is there a way to set the background of [`persistentFooterButtons`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/persistentFooterButtons.html) property, from a Scaffold widget, to **fill all the space** of the footer?

I tried to use a container and set its color property, but it only fills the background up to buttons height.

#### Default

[image]

#### Wrapped with container

[image]

#### Desired result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a default hard-coded padding.

If you using the Flutter Inspector, you will see this:

[image]

If you go into the SDKs `Scaffold.dart` (Ctrl+ click on the `Scaffold` widget), you will see the value is hard coded:

```dart
SafeArea(
            top: false,
            child: IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Container(
                alignment: widget.persistentFooterAlignment,
                // -> Default padding here
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8), 
                child: OverflowBar(
                  spacing: 8,
                  overflowAlignment: OverflowBarAlignment.end,
                  children: widget.persistentFooterButtons!,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

---

One alternative way to tackle this situation could be to create a new Scaffold widget in a separate file and copy the source code from Flutter's original Scaffold to your new class but with your desired modifications (meaning, change the padding to `padding: EdgeInsets.all(0)`).

Answer (score 1):

The `PersistedFooterButtons` shares `backgroundColor` with `Scaffold`. So if you change `backgroundColor` of `Scaffold` it will pick it up. And if you want your `body` to have different background color you can wrap it with `Container` or `ColoredBox` and give it some different color (like I did in the example below).

```
class Sample extends StatelessWidget {
  const Sample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: const ColoredBox(
        // if you want your body to have different background color
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: Center(
          child: Text('test'),
        ),
      ),
      // this changes persistentFooterButtons background color
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      persistentFooterButtons: [
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const Text('Termina'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's an insteresting approach :-)
The only problem with this solution is that widgets, which are children of the body of the Scaffold, hover the persistentFooterButtons content. So even if I can set the background color correctly, my initial problem persists (my goal was to achieve something like the third picture).

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question because I found a way to achieve what I needed, but I'm not using `persistentFooterButtons` anymore, so I think there are more correct answers for this specific thread.

---

The property [`bottomNavigationBar`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/bottomNavigationBar.html) doesn't have a hard coded padding, contrary to `persistentFooterButtons` (as noted by [MendelG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12349734/mendelg) in the other answer).

Therefore, I can change the background color using a Container, and add the padding myself (inside the container) to obtain the wanted result:

```dart
Scaffold(
  // ...
  bottomNavigationBar: Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          // ...
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

#### Result

[image]